# Best way to show all subfolders and its files in uwp

Tags: c#, listview, gridview, tree, uwp-xaml

I have stored all subfolder names and it's corresponding file names(from local folder) in a class. Now I want to display it in a good way. And also need to access that files when user selects it. What is the best way to achieve it?

```
 public class SubFolders
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<SubFolderFiles> SubItemsList { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubFolderFiles
    {
        public string SubItemName { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Best way to show all subfolders and its files in uwp.

For this requirement, you need to create a relatively complete model like the following Illustration.

[image]

The above is recursive model, and I have make a class to match it.

```
public class Folder
{
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<File> _subFiles;
    public ObservableCollection<File> SubFiles
    {
        get { return _subFiles ?? (_subFiles = new ObservableCollection<File>()); }
        set
        {
            _subFiles = value;
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Folder> _subFolder;
    public ObservableCollection<Folder> SubFolders
    {
        get { return _subFolder ?? (_subFolder = new ObservableCollection<Folder>()); }
        set
        {
            _subFolder = value;
        }
    }

    public Folder()
    {

    }
}
public class File
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

As you know, if you want to display the folders and files where in one folder on the `ListView`, you need to converter them into abstract listview items.

```
  public class Item
    {
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public ItemType IType { get; set; }
    }
    public enum ItemType
    {
        File,
        Folder
    }
```

**Usage**

**FolderService.cs**

```
 public class FolderService
 {
     //  private Folder FolderModel;
     public async static Task<Folder> GetFolderInfoAsync(StorageFolder SelectFolder)
     {
         var FolderModel = new Folder();

         FolderModel.FolderName = SelectFolder.Name;
         IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await SelectFolder?.GetFilesAsync();

         foreach (StorageFile file in fileList)
         {
             var subFile = new File();
             subFile.FileName = file.Name;
             FolderModel.SubFiles.Add(subFile);

         }
         IReadOnlyList<StorageFolder> folderList = await SelectFolder?.GetFoldersAsync();

         foreach (StorageFolder folder in folderList)
         {
             var subFolder = new Folder();
             subFolder.FolderName = folder.Name;
             FolderModel.SubFolders.Add(subFolder);

         }

         return FolderModel;
     }
     public async static Task<ObservableCollection<Item>>GetItems(StorageFolder SelectFolder)
     {
         var Model = await GetFolderInfoAsync(SelectFolder);
         var Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
         foreach (var file in Model.SubFiles)
         {
             var item = new Item
             {
                 ItemName = file.FileName,
                 IType = ItemType.File
             };
             Items.Add(item);
         }
         foreach (var folder in Model.SubFolders)
         {
             var item = new Item
             {
                 ItemName = folder.FolderName,
                 IType = ItemType.Folder
             };
             Items.Add(item);
         }
         return Items;
     }
 }
```

**ManPageViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
    }
    public Command PickCommand => new Command(() => this.BtnClick());

    private async void BtnClick()
    {
        StorageFolder Selectfolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        this.Items = await FolderService.GetItems(Selectfolder);
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```